# Navigation Bar Not Populated - iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7, uinavigationitem

A single view in my application refuses to populate the navigation bar in iOS7. I can see the bar is there, enabled, visible and transparent, because my scrollable controls float underneath it when I drag them up. The issue is simply that when I add controls to `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` / `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`, and denote the title of the view (in the ViewController) with `self.title = @"Title";` they do not show in the navigation area.

The strange thing is if I set `self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Title"`, this renders a title on the view in the navigation bar (but is not a solution as it causes problems when navigating elsewhere in the app). The expression "`(self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem != self.navigationItem)`" evaluates true, and I do not understand how this can be the case.

There are other views in the application which render navigation controls properly with the statements shown above.

I should mention that this application performs as expected under iOS6.1. I am pretty new to iPhone dev, so could easily have missed something. Any suggestions for what I could check will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you push the view controller into the navigation controller stack ?

Comment: Possibly incorrectly, the code which was there already read: self.navigationController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.myViewController]; --- updating this with [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.vehicleListViewController animated:YES]; seems to do a much better job of it.

Comment: Does it solve the issue if you actually push view controller instead of using `setViewControllers:animated:` or property setter ? If so, I would consider it to be a bug which should be reported to Apple.

Comment: pushViewController totally rectified my issue, thank you. I'd be happy to mark an answer as correct if you want to submit one. The issue appears to be that you cannot assign ViewControllers direct to the viewControllers property on the navigationController and have it work, this worked in iOS6.1 so perhaps it is a bug as you say. This was used because the previous developer wanted to add two ViewControllers onto the navigation stack but I have used pushViewController twice which accomplishes the same result without issue.

Comment: please submit a bug report to Apple, you might receive a response more worthy to be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was using an incorrect method of pushing the view controller into the navigation controller.

Instead of

```
self.navigationController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.myViewController];
```

Use the following

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.vehicleListViewController animated:YES];
```